# Facebook OAuth "Unhandled remote failure. (Correlation Failed.)"

Tags: c#, facebook, oauth, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an Asp.Net-Core MVC app with external login using Facebook Oauth.

It works perfectly fine on my windows desktop on any browser, but I get the following exception on iOS/iPad on both Safari and Chrome:

```
 Unhandled remote failure. (Correlation Failed.)
```

I've been trying for hours with no luck and I have even compared the web requests (using Fiddler) and they seem to be equivalent, up to the point where the server side exception is thrown.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The date/time on the web browser device was wrong. My iPad had it's datetime set 24 hours into the future.

Setting the correct date+time on the iPad allowed me to correctly login via Facebook on my website.

(I am posting both question and answer to hopefully save a few hours to a future soul.)

Comment: finally someone with the right answer for my problem